# What's wrong in my this SQL Server 2005 query?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005

```
On Error Resume Next
        Dim SQLData As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        Dim cmdSelect As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM a1_ticket WHERE ITC =A1/1007", SQLData)
        SQLData.Open()
        Dim dtrReader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader()
        If dtrReader.HasRows Then
            While dtrReader.Read()
                Literal1.Text = ""
                Literal3.Text = "A1/1008"
                Literal4.Text = dtrReader("Travels")
                Literal5.Text = dtrReader("name")
                Literal6.Text = dtrReader("mob")
                Literal7.Text = dtrReader("fro_m")
                Literal8.Text = dtrReader("t_o")
                Literal9.Text = dtrReader("book_date")
                Literal10.Text = dtrReader("journey_date")
                Literal11.Text = dtrReader("dep_time")
                Literal12.Text = dtrReader("arr_time")
                Literal13.Text = dtrReader("bd_point")
                Literal14.Text = dtrReader("dp_point")
                Literal15.Text = dtrReader("sel_seat")
                Literal16.Text = dtrReader("seat_opt")
                Literal17.Text = dtrReader("bus_type")
                Literal18.Text = dtrReader("taxes")
                Literal19.Text = ""
                Literal20.Text = ""
                Literal21.Text = ""
            End While
        Else
        End If
        dtrReader.Close()
        SQLData.Close()
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? Not the result you expect? Exceptions?

Comment: What error are you getting?  What data type is the ITC field?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you have "On Error Resume Next" in .net code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your char/varchar value should be in single quotes. " ..... = 'A1/1007'  "

Answer (score 1):

My *guess* is that `ITC` is a string column in the DB, so you should have quotes around the value in the query:

```
Dim cmdSelect As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM a1_ticket WHERE ITC ='A1/1007'", SQLData)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM a1_ticket WHERE ITC = **A1/1007**
```

Try, this... your parameter isn't correct. look into SqlParameters

```
SELECT * FROM a1_ticket WHERE ITC = 'A1/1007'
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Hi Marc, i did do that. For whatever reason, Stack doesn't seem to be highlighting the SQL.